# Android Studio 3.5.3 generates some corrupted java class for project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I think Android Studio 3.5.3 has many issues needs to fixed.
Recently I had issue with the Android SDK so I had to uninstall it and reinstall to solve the problem.

Now when I try to open another existing project suddenly it generates corrupted classes some with the name R in that project.

[image: corrupted classes]

I have tried the below options with no success.

1. Invalidate Cache and Restart.
2. Clean and rebuild the project.
3. Sync project with Gradle Files.
4. Sync with Files
5. Exit AS, Delete .deal folder, .gradle folder and .iml files. Then import the project.
6. Again uninstall Android SDK and reinstall.

Unfortunately non of the above helped me.Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what helped me, I had to manually copy the folder with all of the clean java files from the C:\Users\name\Desktop\ProjectName\app\src\main\java\com\ to somewhere safe.

Then I exit Android Studio,Delete everything in \src\main\java\com\ and then i went to the location where i had pasted the folder with my java files, copy them and paste them back to C:\Users\name\Desktop\ProjectName\app\src\main\java\com\

Magical it works,I don't know how but it solved my problem.